# Link в React.js не добавляет слеш

Tags: reactjs, link

При нажатии на кнопку (id="CallBtn") "Заказать звонок" должна появляться форма с анимацией (в блок RequestCall). Закрывается форма после отправки данных, нажатии на кнопку "закрыть" или через переход на предыдущую страницу в браузере (History API). Но проблема в том, что Link не добавляет слеш перед ссылкой, из-за чего не появляется форма. Если обновить страницу, слеш добавляется автоматически, также можно ввести его вручную, тогда анимация формы произойдёт. Но по клику на кнопку "Заказать звонок" ссылка изменяется неверно. Как это исправить?

Ссылка при нажатии на кнопку: http://localhost:3000/?#popup

Ссылка, на которую реагирует анимация: http://localhost:3000/?#/popup

**index.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
 
<head>
    <...>
    <!--Скрипты-->
    <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script defer src="slick/slick.js"></script>
    <script type="text/babel" src="FormClass.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <script defer src="index.js"></script>
</head>
 
<body>
 
    <div id="RequestCall"></div>
 
    <div class="cont">
        <...>
        <div id="callBtn">
        </div>
        <...>
    </div>
 
    </body>
```

**index.js**

```js
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import CallLink from './CallLink';
//import { Route, BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Route, HashRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import Form from './FormClass';
 
render(
    <HashRouter>
            <CallLink />
    </HashRouter>
    , document.getElementById('callBtn'));
 
render(
    <HashRouter>
        <Route exact path="/popup" component={Form} />
    </HashRouter>
    , document.getElementById('RequestCall'));
```

**CallLink.js**

```js
import React from 'react'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'
 
const CallLink = () => {
    return (
        <Link to="/popup" >
            <div className="btn-main call">Заказать звонок</div>
        </Link>
    )
}
 
export default CallLink;
```

**FormClass.js**

```js
import React from 'react'
import { CSSTransitionGroup } from 'react-transition-group'
import './call.css'
import CloseButton from './CloseButton';
class Form extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        
        let fio = window.localStorage.getItem("fio") || "";
        let phone = window.localStorage.getItem("phone") || "";
        let region = window.localStorage.getItem("region") || "";
        let message = window.localStorage.getItem("message") || "";
        this.state = {
            fio: fio,
            phone: phone,
            region: region,
            message: message
        }
        
        this.changeFIO = this.changeFIO.bind(this);
        this.changePhone = this.changePhone.bind(this);
        this.changeMessage = this.changeMessage.bind(this);
        this.changeRegion = this.changeRegion.bind(this);
        this.send = this.send.bind(this);
        this.resetForm = this.resetForm.bind(this);
    }
    
    changeFIO(event) {
        this.setState({
            fio: event.target.value
        });
        window.localStorage.setItem("fio", event.target.value);
    }
    
    changePhone(event) {
        this.setState({
            phone: event.target.value
        });
        window.localStorage.setItem("phone", event.target.value);
    }
    
    changeRegion(event) {
        this.setState({
            region: event.target.value
        });
        window.localStorage.setItem("region", event.target.value);
    }
    
    changeMessage(event) {
        this.setState({
            message: event.target.value
        });
        window.localStorage.setItem("message", event.target.value);
    }
    
    resetForm() {
        window.localStorage.setItem("fio", "");
        window.localStorage.setItem("phone", "");
        window.localStorage.setItem("region", "");
        window.localStorage.setItem("message", "");
        this.setState({
            fio: "",
            phone: "",
            region: "",
            message: ""
        });
        window.CallUs.reset();
        window.history.back();
    }
    
    send() {
        document.getElementById('sendBtn').disabled = true;
        fetch("https://api.slapform.com/тут моя почта", {
            method: "POST",
            body: JSON.stringify(this.state),
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json"
            },
        }).then(
            result => {
            alert("Мы скоро свяжемся с вами!");
            document.getElementById('sendBtn').disabled = false;
            this.resetForm();
            },
            error => {
                document.getElementById('sendBtn').disabled = false;
                let repeat = window.confirm("Ошибка! Повторить отправку?");
                if (repeat) this.send();
            }
        )
    }
 
    render() {
        return (
            <CSSTransitionGroup
                transitionName="callTransition"
                transitionAppear={true}
                transitionAppearTimeout={500}
                transitionEnter={false}
                transitionLeave={false}>
                <div className="popupAgr mfp-hide pop_up" >
                    <form name="CallUs" id="CallUs" acceptCharset="UTF-8">
                        <div><input id="fio" className="inputPopup1 grey" type="text" value={this.state.fio} onChange={this.changeFIO} placeholder="ФИО" required /></div>
                        <div><input id="phone" className="inputPopup1 grey" type="tel" value={this.state.phone} onChange={this.changePhone} placeholder="Телефон" required /></div>
                        <select id="region" value={this.state.region} onChange={this.changeRegion} placeholder="Телефон" className="inputPopup2" required>
                            <option value="" disabled>Регион</option>
                            <option value="Республика Адыгея">Республика Адыгея</option>
                            <option value="Республика Башкортостан">Республика Башкортостан</option>
                            <option value="Республика Бурятия">Республика Бурятия</option>
                            <option value="Республика Алтай">Республика Алтай</option>
                            <option value="Республика Дагестан">Республика Дагестан</option>
                            <option value="Республика Ингушетия">Республика Ингушетия</option>
                            <option value="Кабардино-Балкарская Республика">Кабардино-Балкарская Республика</option>
                            <option value="Республика Калмыкия">Республика Калмыкия</option>
                            <option value="Карачаево-Черкесская Республика">Карачаево-Черкесская Республика</option>
                            <option value="Республика Карелия">Республика Карелия</option>
                            <option value="Республика Коми">Республика Коми</option>
                            <option value="Республика Марий Эл">Республика Марий Эл</option>
                            <option value="Республика Мордовия">Республика Мордовия</option>
                            <option value="Республика Саха">Республика Саха</option>
                            <option value="Республика Северная Осетия - Алания">Республика Северная Осетия - Алания</option>
                            <option value="Республика Татарстан">Республика Татарстан</option>
                            <option value="Республика Тыва">Республика Тыва</option>
                            <option value="Удмуртская Республика">Удмуртская Республика</option>
                            <option value="Республика Хакасия">Республика Хакасия</option>
                            <option value="Чеченская Республика">Чеченская Республика</option>
                            <option value="Чувашская Республика">Чувашская Республика</option>
                            <option value="Алтайский край">Алтайский край</option>
                            <option value="Краснодарский край">Краснодарский край</option>
                            <option value="Красноярский край">Красноярский край</option>
                            <option value="Приморский край">Приморский край</option>
                            <option value="Ставропольский край">Ставропольский край</option>
                            <option value="Хабаровский край">Хабаровский край</option>
                        </select>
                        <div><textarea className="inputPopup3 grey" id="mess" value={this.state.message} onChange={this.changeMessage} placeholder="Cообщение"></textarea></div>
                        <div><button id="sendBtn" className="btn-main" type="button" onClick={this.send}>Отправить</button></div>
                        <div><CloseButton /></div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </CSSTransitionGroup>
        );
    }
}
export default Form;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

на сколько мне известно, `<Link>` может работать только внутри `<Router>`.
ссылка работает таким принципом, что при её нажатии, она ищет ближайших `<Router>` и по нему идет переход. у Вас же она заходит в тупик, так как внутри

```
render(
    <HashRouter>
            <CallLink />
    </HashRouter>
    , document.getElementById('callBtn'));
```

нет `<Router>`.

**+** обратите внимание, что Ваши ссылки типа `http://localhost:3000/...` работают только у Вас локально на хосте (ПК), так как это равносильно тому, что линкануть свой путь к папке на ПК (**С/programm_Files/...**) - пусть один, а результат у каждого разный

Comment: Спасибо) Исправлю. А насчёт localhost, я просто с локального сервера тестирую, прежде чем на хостинг заливать

Comment: Закинул их в один Router, но работает также. Ссылка выводится без слеша, и изменений не происходит

Comment: а можно на Ваш проект посмотреть?)
ссылку на gitHub, было бы очень удобно